# Doctrine2: additional connection options

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to add some additional parameters to the database connection in Doctrine2?

For example I need to enable network communication compression.

```
$DoctrineConnectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname' => 'db',
    'user' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    /* 
    additional_options => array(
       PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_COMPRESS => true
    )
    */
);
$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($DoctrineConnectionOptions, $DoctrineConfig);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check EntityManager::create() source code. You can directly pass customly made PDO object as a connection option ('pdo' key).